# Problem in Path @Alias ​with Create-React-App

Tags: create-react-app

It just isn't finding the *.svg image, if I add a .TSX file it finds it, however, I already configured the *.svg .d.ts module, what's wrong?

```
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 4:0-64
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@assets/imgs/teste.svg' in 'APP_NAME\src'
```

**REACT-APP-IMPORT.D.TS**

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import React = require('react');

    export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
    const src: string;
    export default src;
}
```

**TSCONFIG.JSON**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"],
            "@assets/*": ["assets/*"]
        },
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    },
    "include": ["src", "src/react-app-import.d.ts", ".eslintrc"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "build", "coverage"]
}
```

**APP.TSX**

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '@assets/imgs/teste.svg';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <h1>
            Hello World <Logo />
        </h1>
    );
}
```